# Most efficient sorting algorithm to continuously sort an vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, algorithm, real-time

What is the fastest algorithm to keep a

```
vector<vector<double>>
```

continuously "merge" sorted being able to handle updates in realtime?

For example, at T0 `vec<vector<double>` is empty

At T1, (in fact only one `vec<double>` comes in at once)

```
A = 1, 2, 4
B = 1, 3, 4, 5
C = 6, 7
```

The `vector<vector>` gets merge-sorted into,

1
1
2
3
4
4
5
6
7

At T2

```
C = 0, 4
D = 3, 7
```

The new list would be

> 0
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   3
>   4
>   4
>   4
>   5
>   7

So first we have to remove the old values of C, then "insert" the new values of C correctly.

Some sort function like this `AVL_Tree Func(vector<vector<double>> vecvec, vector<double> newVec)` that returns tree would seem to be best. AVL Tree? Can someone show me a c++ templatized version of code that would work? Boost, STL etc use is fine.

Comment: What do you want to do with this list after it is sorted?  The answer depends on whether you want to binary search it, iterate over the first few items, etc.

Comment: I want to traverse it in order and draw the values. But I may want to ask questions of it. Imagine instead of just numbers, the values are struct, but the primary sorted value is a number.

Comment: I wonder if a priority_queue (or something similar to that) might be a better data structure to use than a vector of vectors?

Comment: `std::set` is a tree which will be more efficient than AVL. But what are you actually trying to do? What is the significance of the two levels of `vector`? Re-sorting a `vector` after every insertion will always be `O(n^2 log n)` and you probably don't want that.

Comment: How about using an multiset<double> for the sorted list, and having a vector<vector<pair<double, multiset<double>::iterator> > > instead? Then you could easily remove from the multiset when removing from the 2d-vector.